# Very simple bar graph

Tags: r, aggregation

First I will have to apologize for my ignorance as I'm sure this is a very simple question but I am very new to R. My question is that I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
countrydes       Insured

USA               4500
CANADA            4500 
USA               7500
CANADA            7600
```

All I want to do is aggregate the sum of the insured value by country and produce a bar graph e.g.

```
countrydes        Insured 

USA                12000       
Canada             12100
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that has made my life alot easier.

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
# Define your data
dfr <- data.frame(
   countrydes=rep(c("USA", "CANADA"), 2), 
   Insured=c(4500, 4500, 7500, 7600))
# Sum by country
totals <- with(dfr, by(Insured, countrydes, sum))
# Plot the answer
barplot(totals)
```

(As Etiennebr mentioned, you could use `aggregate` instead of `by`, in which case you need to coerce `countrydes` to be a list.)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply sum each one separatly. Let's call your data frame df :

```
USA <- sum(df[df$countrydes=="USA",]$Insured)
CANADA <- sum(df[df$countrydes=="CANADA",]$Insured)
```

But with aggregate() you can handle all the countries in one line.

```
 aggsumcount <- aggregate(x=df$Insured,by=list(df$countrydes),FUN=sum)
```